# How do I get logs for the startup sequence if I use Spring External log4j.properties file?

Tags: spring, properties, log4j, external

So the problem is that the start-up sequence for this application is important because it needs to get some information from the database when it starts up for the first time. If I use this in the web.xml file:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:log4j.applicationName.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
    <param-value>10000</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

The problem with the above is that it takes Spring 10000... Milliseconds? ..so then 10 seconds to load the properties file and I don't see any of the start-up sequence in the logs.

Comment: I may have actually solved this. It seems the log4j config in web.xml must come before the context load listener entry:

<listener>
        <listener-class>            org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

This combined with a reduction of the log4jRefreshInterval to 1 second seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yup. It has to come before the context load listener.